# How to convert this curl command to httparty in Rails? Using Orange SMS Api

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, curl, httparty, orange-api

I'm trying to use [Orange SMS API](https://developer.orange.com/apis/), I read how to use it [here](https://developer.orange.com/apis/sms-eg/getting-started).

I want to use this api from Rails application.

I want to convert this curl command to httparty code.

```
curl -X POST \
-H "Authorization: {authorization_header}" \
-d "grant_type=client_credentials" \
https://api.orange.com/oauth/v2/token
```

I searched for many solutions, but all failed :(

here's the last try

```
HTTParty.post(
      "https://api.orange.com/oauth/v2/token",
      headers: { 
        "Content-Type" => "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", 
        "Authorization" => "Basic {authorization_header}",
        "Accept" => "application/json"
      },
      body: {
        :grant_type => "client_credentials"
      }.to_json
    )
```

but I receive this error:

> ## ## 504 Gateway Time-out
>
> \nThe server didn't respond in time.\n\n", @response=#, @headers={"date"=>["Wed, 21 Sep 2016 13:35:37 GMT"], "cache-control"=>["no-cache"], "content-type"=>["text/html; charset=UTF-8"], "connection"=>["close"], "transfer-encoding"=>["chunked"]}>
>
> irb(main):073:0>

I also tried this way

```
       access_token = HTTParty.post(
         "https://api.orange.com/oauth/v2/token",
         headers: { "Content-Type" => "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "Authorization" => "Basic {authorization_header}"},
         query: { "grant_type" => "client_credentials" }
       )
```

but I get this error:

> => #"invalid_grant", "error_description"=>"The paramater grant_type is not valid."}, @response=#, @headers={"date"=>["Wed, 21 Sep 2016 13:14:18 GMT"], "host"=>["ope-apigee-private"], "content-type"=>["application/json"], "authorization"=>["Basic cWVnaUJlR0xhcndaYzZ0R1dtS1JqUFE2d0FBOVNEWW46SFJ1SGFURUJlOHR2aHlTOA=="], "x-forwarded-for"=>["213.181.226.205, 192.168.70.3", "192.168.9.45"], "x-forwarded-host"=>["api.orange.com"], "x-forwarded-server"=>["OPOPECBALLAP04"], "content-length"=>["86"], "connection"=>["close"]}>

I don't know how to use it I read the official way and it worked using Curl but I can't do it in Rails.

Comment: 504 Gateway Time-out is usually due to network connection errors and not the actual request itself. When sending `"Content-Type" => "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"` you should not JSON encode the request body.

Comment: Wow.. It worked!! Thank you very much. I just removed "to_json".

Comment: Usually when using OAuth it makes sense to use the [Oauth](https://github.com/oauth-xx/oauth-ruby) or [Oauth2](https://github.com/intridea/oauth2) gems instead of a "basic" HTTP lib like httparty.